# In the Hammer parser combinator, how do you implement a rule that refers to itself?

Tags: perl, parsing, parser-combinators

I'm getting a "Deep recursion on subroutine" warning when I just refer to the name as shown in the code below. [use 5.016 … `__SUB__`->()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__SUB__.html) does not help, either.

Build hints: [git clone](https://github.com/UpstandingHackers/hammer) ; scons bindings=perl test ; cd build/opt/src/bindings/perl ; $EDITOR h.pl

```
use 5.024;
use strictures;
use blib;
use hammer qw();

# digits = "0" / "1" / "2" / "3" / "4" / "5" / "6" / "7" / "8" / "9"
sub digits { hammer::many hammer::in 0..9 }

# product = digits "*" digits
sub product {
    hammer::sequence digits, hammer::ch('*'), digits
}

product->parse('23*42'); # [[2, 3], '*', [4, 2]]


# mproduct = digits "*" mproduct
sub mproduct;
sub mproduct {
    hammer::sequence digits, hammer::ch('*'), mproduct
}
mproduct->parse('8*23*42');
# Deep recursion on subroutine "main::mproduct" at h.pl line 21.
```

Comment: If [hammer](https://github.com/abiggerhammer/hammer) is a recursive descent parser, then aren't self-referring rules disallowed?

Comment: How do you figure it's rec.descent?

Comment: I read as much of the docs/hammer-presentation.pdf as I could and some of the source. Did I misinterpret something? I'm unfamiliar with that code and I have an interest in finding faster parsers, which the authors claim hammer is. Your question perked my interest.

Comment: @jeff6times, Recursion is not disallowed in recursive decent parsers --it's right there in the name!-- it's left-recursion that doesn't work. (ok: `foo: bar foo baz`; not ok: `foo: foo bar baz`)

Comment: @ikegami Hello, again. The exclamation point was unnecessary. BTW, I'm keeping track of these.

Comment: Note that `mproduct` is called *before* you call `parse` to generate a parse tree. `mproduct` unconditonally calls `mproduct`, thus the infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has an infinite loop: `mproduct` unconditonally calls `mproduct`.

Your grammar also has the same an infinite loop: `mproduct` is unconditionally defined in terms of `mproduct`.

```
mproduct ::= digits '*' mproduct
```

The grammar you want is

```
mproduct ::= digits '*' mproduct
           | digits
```

or

```
mproduct  ::= digits mproduct_
mproduct_ ::= '*' mproduct_
            | ε
```

To put it more clearly using pseudo-BNF, the grammar you want is

```
myproduct ::= digits ( '*' digits )*
```

`hammer` provides a tool to implement this:

```
hammer::sepBy1(digits, hammer::ch('*'))
```

---

That doesn't address the more general question. The following is a case where the answer to general question would be useful:

```
expr ::= sum

sum  ::= term sum_
sum_ ::= '+' sum_
       | ε

term ::= num
       | '(' expr ')'
```

The broken approach would be:

```
sub num { ... }

sub term {
   hammer::choice(
      num(),
      hammer::sequence(
         hammer::ch('('),
         expr(),
         hammer::ch(')'),
      )
   )
}

sub sum { hammer::sepBy1(term, hammer::ch('+')) }

sub expr { sum() }

my $parser = expr();
```

The solve this problem, one would use `bind_indirect`.

```
use feature qw( state );

sub num { ... }

sub term {
   hammer::choice(
      num(),
      hammer::sequence(
         hammer::ch('('),
         expr(),
         hammer::ch(')'),
      )
   )
}

sub sum { hammer::sepBy1(term, hammer::ch('+')) }

sub _expr { sum() }
sub expr { state $expr = hammer::indirect(); $expr }
UNITCHECK { hammer::bind_indirect(expr(), _expr()); }

my $parser = expr();
```

---

The [test file](https://github.com/UpstandingHackers/hammer/tree/master/src/bindings/perl/t) proved useful in answering this question.

Nothing is tested.